# Plugging in your own IoC container in NServiceBus 4

Tags: nservicebus, ioc-container

It seems that in version 5 of [NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/) the API allows you to [inject an instance of your own IoC container into NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers) with the following syntax:

```
configuration.UseContainer<UnityBuilder>(c => c.UseExistingContainer(unityContainer));
```

The only mentioned syntax for version 4 is as follows:

```
  Configure.With().UsingContainer<UnityObjectBuilder>();
```

Is it correct that you cannot inject an instance of your own container in version 4 of NServiceBus? I.e. you can only tell NServiceBus to use another container, but *not* yours specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's supported.  The syntax is:

```
Configure.With().UnityBuilder(container);
```

Comment: Yep that was correct, and for reference, you'll need two NuGet packages for this. `Unity.Interception` and `NServiceBus.Unity`.